# Show one List field Text over an image

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have set an image inside a `<div class ="Image">` to display.

Now, I want to show one field from my SharePoint List column which is of date type over the image at the bottom position.

Can you please suggest How can I achieve embedding the Column value on that image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are able to fetch the value only problem is with the positioning.

Please refer below link, which give an sample of positioning text over image.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css

Hope it give you idea

Comment: Yes, I can fetch the value.

Comment: Can not add the list column value to the image as per the url you provided.

Comment: I have 
<div class="ImageTest">
<img id ="image" src="/imageurl/imagetest.jpj"/>
<p id ="Text"></P>
</div>
now i have value of column in a variable "date"
how can I reflect taht inside the image .